# Ansible + why yum not install the latest version

Tags: linux, yum

I am installed successfully the ansible tool from yum repository as

```
yuminstallansible
```

ansible is great tool even more then puppet

- From site - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#getting-ansible

but after yum installation I see that the ansible isn’t the latest version

```
ansible--version
ansible1.1
```

- Ansible releases - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases

please advice why yum not install the latest ansible version ( 1.9 )

Answer (score 0):

You must configure EPEL first: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/ansible.html

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to install Ansible with pip.

pip will get you the latest version much more quickly than yum